# How to increase the size of PrimeNg loadingIcon

Tags: primeng, primeng-turbotable, primeicons

In the PrimeNg Turbotable I use loadingIcon to display the spinner while loading data. I am not able to increase the size of primeIcon pi-spinner.

HTML Code:

```html
<p-table #resdt exportFilename="RecordChange"  [value]="recordList"  
      [(selection)]="selectedRecord" [loadingIcon]="loadingIcon" 
      [loading]="loading" sortField="recordCURD" sortMode="single" 
      [autoLayout]="true" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="550px">
....
</p-table>
```

TypeScript Code:

```js
this.loadingIcon = 'pi pi-spin pi-spinner';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you just need to update the wrapper class for the loading element like this

*style.css*

```css
.ui-table .ui-table-loading-icon {
    font-size: 5em !important;
}
```

or as we can set the icon class ,so this can be simply done by create a new class to increase the font size

```css
.loading-icon-size { 
  font-size: 5em !important;
 }
```

*template*

```html
<p-table .... [loading]="loading" loadingIcon="
    pi pi-spin pi-spinner loading-icon-size ">
 .....
</table>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablelazy-demo-ubvto8?file=src/app/app.component.ts)